# Firestore @PropertyName annotation giving strange error?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my data class:

```
import com.google.firebase.firestore.PropertyName

data class MHatchery(
   @set:PropertyName("hName")
   var hName:String,
   val hLocation:String,
)
```

Now when I try to enter values, it's giving this error:

> Found setter on com.***.***.***.models.MHatchery with invalid case-sensitive name: setHName

I am finding it difficult to understand, what's this setHName?? Why am I getting this error? What I am using is `hName`. Then what's this `setHName` all about? Please help me understand where am I getting it wrong?

Firestore versions I'm using:

```
// Import the Firebase BoM
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.2.1')

//Firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'

//Firebase Auth UI
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:7.2.0'

//Firebase Database
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx"

//FireStore
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:23.0.2'
```

and this is my gradle dependencies

```
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21"
```

This is my database screenshot. I want hname to be like `hName`. That's why I am trying @PropertyName annotation

[image]

Comment: I have no clue for this error but maybe try creating a setter of your own, with the correct name to see if it changes anything?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo Added screenshot.

Comment: I see, I'll write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> Found setter on com.***.***.***.models.MHatchery with invalid case-sensitive name: setHName

Because the names of the fields in your `MHatchery` class are different from the ones in the database. For example, in your class, you have a property called `hName`, with a capital `N`, while in your database the field is called `hname`, with a lower-case `n`. To be able to map a Firestore document into an object of type `MHatchery`, the name of the properties must match.

There are two ways in which you can solve this issue. The first one would be to change the name of the fields in your class to match the ones in the database. So you should change:

```
var hName:String,
```

To:

```
var hname:String,
```

And remove the annotation:

```
//@set:PropertyName("hName")
```

Or you add the following annotations in front of the property like this:

```
@get:PropertyName("hName")
@set:PropertyName("hName")
var hName:String,
```

Comment: Even if the database is empty, its giving the same error.

Comment: That's most likely because of `@set:PropertyName("hName")`. A property called `hName`, doesn't exist, hence the error.

Comment: Does it work with the solution in my answer?

Comment: If i am adding both set and get, its working

Comment: So need to add both set and get for this to work. The third line @PropertyName("hName") is not needed

Comment: Good to hear that it's working, Shijilal ;) I just updated my answer.

Comment: Sure. It was very helpful. Also if you could edit set and get to hName, instead of hname it would be helpful for other too.,because that's what i was looking for

Comment: I just did. Cheers ;)